# What could be causing an unexpected error when trying to edit a root folder name?

Tags: publishing-site, error, folder, parser-error

I am using sharepoint 2010 publishing site. When I go to the gui part of sharepoint 2010(allitem.aspx) and go to one of my libraries, check a folder, go to the ribbon and hit edit properties and try to change the folders name I get this error

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: s   
 at System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)    
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WorkflowUtilities.FlattenXmlToHashtable(String strXml)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WorkflowUtilities.DoesWorkflowCancelWhenItemEdited(String associationXml)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.EnsurePageNotInLockingWorkflowIfInEditMode()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.LoadDataSource()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ConsoleDataSource.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.XmlConsoleDataSource.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.PublishingSiteActionsMenuCustomizer.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I tried the solution from [this post](http://www.thorntontechnical.com/tech/sharepoint/sharepoint-workflow-list-item-edit-argumentnullexception) but I still have the problem.

Comment: could you pull out the 14/logs logs ?

Comment: We need more information to answer your question. Please [edit] your post and add details as requested by the community. It will be closed for now, but don't worry - once you have improved the question flag a moderator and it can be reopened. See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for general guidelines.